# How to change the dendrogram labels in python

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have this:

[image: my result]

And I want to have 25 clusters. So I used this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 25, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'ward')
y_hc = hc.fit_predict(df)
df['class'] = y_hc
```

Now to show these clusters I used this code however in the labels it shows label count but I want to show the cluster lable

```
linkage_matrix = hierarchy.linkage(df.iloc[:, :-2], method='ward', metric='euclidean')

# Plot the dendrogram
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

dendrogram = hierarchy.dendrogram(linkage_matrix,labels=df['cluster'].values,p=25,truncate_mode='lastp',leaf_font_size=10, leaf_rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Genomes')
plt.ylabel('Euclidean distances')
plt.title(f'Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram (method="ward")')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `df` is not defined.  presumably a dataframe or some kind.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)